# How to resize text when app goes full screen

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, textfield, autoresize

I created a Label (TextField) in swift which resizes when my macOS app goes full screen.
But the text inside the textfield still have same size.It is not resizing.
**How to resize text with screen size or with the textfield size?**
Please help me with this.

Comment: Please read the guidelines for submitting questions on Stack Overflow. This question has zero code, little information, shows little to no effort, and is a question with an extremely obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

To detect fullscreen changes, add observers in your view controller's `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didEnterFullscreen), name: NSWindow.didEnterFullScreenNotification, object: self.view.window)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didExitFullscreen), name: NSWindow.didExitFullScreenNotification, object: self.view.window)
```

Then set the text field's `font` property in `didEnterFullscreen` and `didExitFullscreen`.

However, a much more versatile solution would be to update the font whenever the text field changes size:

```swift
class AutoResizableTextField: NSTextField {
    
    override var frame: NSRect {
        didSet {
            // Find the max font size that does not cause the text to exceed our frame
            var font = self.font?.withSize(1) ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1)
            var string = attributedStringValue
            // Increase font size until the text just barely fits
            while true {
                font = font.withSize(font.pointSize + 1)
                // Calculate the size of the text with this font
                let next = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: string)
                next.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length))
                var size = next.size()
                // Pad the size a bit to prevent clipping
                size.width += 6
                size.height += 6
                if size.width > frame.width || size.height > frame.height { break }
                string = next
            }
            // Set the font
            attributedStringValue = string
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure to set `textField.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]` to let the field resize whenever the window resizes.